# Search in array with property name in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any jquery function to get specifc data by any property from list?

Here is my array in page.

```
[{"ConId":0,"ConCurIdSource":1,"ConCurIdTarget":10,"ConConversionRate":0.27,"IsActive":null,"CreatedBy":null,"CreatedDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedDate":null,"Abbrivation":"AEDTOPKR"},

{"ConId":0,"ConCurIdSource":10,"ConCurIdTarget":1,"ConConversionRate":27,"IsActive":null,"CreatedBy":null,"CreatedDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedDate":null,"Abbrivation":"PKRTOAED"},

{"ConId":0,"ConCurIdSource":10,"ConCurIdTarget":14,"ConConversionRate":101,"IsActive":null,"CreatedBy":null,"CreatedDate":null,"UpdatedBy":null,"UpdatedDate":null,"Abbrivation":"PKRTOUSD"}]
```

i need to get  all maching object by **Abbrivation**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for jQuery, just use the standard [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function :

```
var matches = myArray.filter(function(v){ return v.Abbrivation==="PKRTOAED" });
```

Answer (score 1):

a more neat solution is to use jQuery `.grep()` as following

```
new_array = jQuery.grep(my_array, function( a ) {
  return a.prop == "YOUR_DESIRED_VALUE";
});
```

Source:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/